# Pandas row function row iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a maximum value:

```
max_factor = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],'b':np.random.randn(10)})
df
   a         b
0  1 -0.424957
1  1  1.893320
2  1  0.187929
3  2 -1.413340
4  2  1.737371
5  2  0.959317
6  3 -0.554445
7  3  0.100595
8  3 -0.176009
9  3  0.430475
```

I want to create another column 'c' and populate it with values that depend on values in 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

For example:

```
if value(a) == 1 or value(a) == 2:
    value(c) = 0
else:
    value(c) = value(b)/max_factor + value(c-1)
```

I have tried multiple ways to do this but am struggling. Do I have to iterate through each row or is there a faster way to do this?

EDIT: The actual function to generate the values in column 'c' is more complicated but this would be a great starting point.

Comment: do you mean `value(a -1)` or `value(c-1)`?

Comment: value(c-1) as in, the value of 'c' in the row above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple conditions besides this example you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def foo(row):
    if row['a'] == 1 or row['a'] == 2:
        global v
        v = 0
    else:
        v_old = v
        v = row['b']/20+v_old

    return v

df['c'] = df.apply(foo,axis=1)

   a         b         c
0  1  0.858951  0.000000
1  1  0.588102  0.000000
2  1  1.452569  0.000000
3  2  1.400972  0.000000
4  2 -0.921342  0.000000
5  2 -1.117748  0.000000
6  3  0.792742  0.039637
7  3  0.254630  0.052369
8  3  0.351391  0.069938
9  3  1.822267  0.161052
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solved half my problem. The hard(?) part is where each value of 'c' depends on the value of 'c' in the row above. I.e. c(n) = c(n-1) + function(a and b)

Comment: Will c always have an initial value? That means will the equation you're running start at c[1] or higher and not c[0]?

Comment: when 'a' == 2 c has to be 0. So I guess that is the initial value? when 'c' > 2. c(n) just depends on a, b, and c(n-1). The initial value of c(n-1) should be 0

Comment: If your data is organized as you have it here, a quick way to do it is `df['c']+=df['c'].shift(1)`. Otherwise you'll need to create an incremental value then call the row based on that location -1. It's possible, but if your data is organized it's very quick with shifting it